# How do I write a typescript template literal using a union twice without invalid permutations?

Tags: typescript

I currently am trying to sort out how to create a string literal type that maps table and fields  `${Table}.${Field} as ${Field}`, but I can't seem to get the typescript type right.

[The documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#string-unions-in-types) isn't abundantly clear on what happens when a union is used more than once.

It appears that TypeScript treats every substitution in a template literal type independent of each other, so if you specify the same substitution in a template literal, where the generic value is a union, it will consider mismatched substitutions for the same variable valid. Is there a way to prevent this so that if I want to use the same value from a union twice in the template, it uses the same value?

Typescript 4.9.4

```js
type QualifiedField<Table extends string, Field extends string> = Field | `${Table}.${Field} as ${Table}_${Field}`;

let test: QualifiedField<'test', 'BIG' | 'small'>;
test = 'BIG'; // ✅ Wanted
test = 'small'; // ✅ Wanted
test = 'test.BIG as test_BIG'; // ✅ Wanted
test = 'test.BIG as test_small'; // ❌ I don't want this
test = 'test.small as test_small'; // ✅ Wanted
test = 'test.small as test_BIG'; // ❌ I don't want this
test = 'this fails'; // ✅ Expected error: Type '"this fails"' is not assignable to type...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can prevent the invalid permutations by [distributing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) over `Field` in a conditional type where we store each constituent inside a new inferred type `F`. For each *"iteration"* over the `Field` union, the `F` type is guaranteed to be a non-union string literal type.

```
type QualifiedField<Table extends string, Field extends string> = 
  Field | (Field extends infer F extends string 
    ? `${Table}.${F} as ${Table}_${F}` 
    : never
  )
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=91&pln=13&pc=86#code/C4TwDgpgBAigrgQwDYEsBmKIBMBimlYA8AKggEZLQQAewEAdlgM5RPABOK9A5gDRR4IBKDTqMWbTjwB8UALxQAUFAH4sUAD5QAFIOGiGzKFzQR2AkbUMSOXblAD8UAAYASAN6kKEAL4A6DxwfKAQWDy9KHwB9QJ9nKAAuKHoIADczAEpFRVBIKGIABnlYRFQMbD0iAHI6Nir+KoAhAEkAcSrNKCqmAFtkJCrpAG5symAoWuAk+GR0TFw1QhqIOoaW9s7uvqQB4ZyV8YUmtqqhqAB6c6hAUHIoAHUEejosfbZirf7Ti6vbh6fsV6HLqTPzrEIsSZRdZfS43e6PZ6A94gsGhCYHKK9T5nWGAGXIoM0oFgAPb0GpQADuCImAAsUEwkUcQViduD0WxMdsBjifvD-i9JsiDn4WUg2ZDoTyoPjCSSyeMqU9afTGcC6Sw0AgUEgmDDeQBRaiQADGzxE7HYxPYSWI4GgVQARMB1VBNdqmA6OvTksTxqEmChuPRyJQJsSJna-FGgA)

Comment: Oh wow, thanks; I don't think I would have stumbled upon that by chance. I'll have to read up more on `infer` as I have seen it digging around some libraries, but have weak understanding of it's usage.